# Jackson deserialize string to default enum

Tags: java, json, serialization, enums, jackson

I am deserializing a field from JSON to my custom enum. The requirement that I have is that if the JSON field string is not the part of my enum, it should deserialize it to the `DEFAULT` enum value.

Here is my enum.

```
public enum Status {

    Y("Y"),

    N("N"),

    U("U"),

    A("A"),

    C("C"),

    R("R"),

    UNKNOWN(/* any other string value */) // this is what i need


    private final String textualValue;


    Status(String textualValue) {
        this.textualValue = Objects.requireNonNull(textualValue);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return textualValue;
    }
```

So, basically if a JSON contains something like `{"status":"X"}`, I want that to deserialized into `Status.UNKNOWN`, just as now ie. {"status":"A"} deserializes into `Status.A`.

I am doing my mappings with `ObjectMapper`.

```
protected static final ObjectMapper jsonMapper =
        new ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
        .enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING)
        .enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);
```

Is something like that possible?

Comment: as you are using jaskon you can create a custom deserializer.

Comment: An enum constant is a singleton. You can't possibly have several different instances of Status.UNKNOWN having different textual values.

Comment: @JBNizet They don't need to have different textual values. But the different textual values need to be serialized to the same enum constant.

Comment: Then your enum example is very confusing.